# Deserialize the json and extract the pdf from it?

Tags: c#, json

JSON response I am receiving:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "pdfString": "JVBERi0xLjcKJeLjz9M"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "msg": "Data Successfully Retrived"
}
```

Code to  read the  json

```
var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
Example1 dat = (Example1)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText, typeof(Example1));
if (dat.status == "success")
{

    string pdfString = dat.data[0][0].value;

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfString.Length.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;");
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
    Response.BinaryWrite(Convert.FromBase64String(pdfString));

}
```

Models

```
public class Example1
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<List<Datum>> data { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
}
```

I have written the code to read the JSON format and  class How can I read the pdfstring value.

I want  convert it into  PDF after reading it. Here I am facing the issue  how to read it?

Comment: Not an answer, but content length would be the number of bytes, not length of Base64.

Comment: Use JSON.NET for deserializing the json result. Please explain further regarding the pdf; do you get it as a link to the location, or the binary tha represents it.

Comment: Am I wrong to think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699407/how-to-convert-from-string-into-pdf) could help you ?

Comment: @Fabulous   I am already using same

Comment: Please elaborate on "issue how to read it". What happens that is not what you want?

Comment: I want to read the value of the pdfstring I am using the following:                                 string pdfString = dat.data[0][0].value;                        //here getting null

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null value because your model does not match the JSON.
You need a dictionary to handle the key-value pairs instead of `Datum`.

```
public class Example1
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> data { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

After deserializing to `Example1`, you can retrieve the `pdfString` like this:

```
string pdfString = dat.data[0][0]["pdfString"];
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3mnnNs