# C# save PDF/TIFF string to a file

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting PDF and TIFF files as a string. How do I save this string as file. This is not base 64 encoded.

I cant just save the text like this. I get an error when opening up the pdf "Insufficient data for an image"

```
string fileData = "%PDF-1.5.........";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:/test.pdf", fileData);
```

Example of PDF

```
%PDF-1.5
1 0 obj
<<
/Creator ()
/CreationDate (20200731214227)
/ModDate (20200731214227)
/Author ()
/Producer ()
/Title ()
/Subject ()
/Keywords ()
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids [4 0 R ]
/Count 1
/MediaBox [0 0 0 0]
>>

....

>>
startxref
5399
%%EOF
```

Example of Tiff

```
II* �  &�l��UX�������i����������������������������������������-+ �꟧�k��O��'���ȁ�"5��]zO�O�O�������/��������}���w�Hgkv����1W�~��jC��S�f
��>�կ�
cһ�w�w�w��L?���������O���_�~ׯ������W��5��H��7���/b���׆������-|�1�o��x��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������P ����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������j/�r�*_����������_������ׯ���������������������������������^a�������׭����������������������������������o����������h��[�������������������������������7��}������-A������w��������������������������������߇����?������������}��������}����ｃ����������̉�۾���|;�2JB��|;��ӽ��w�xA����N��w������xD2Ckf���]������� Y�7���[-�=[������hؐxD�3i�;�;���ޡ��[��� f���w�`�D��XzxD�J��!���������zxA�����xOOO==< �����O==< �������OO==< �������==< ������OOA�=< �������z}�=���������=��������|0���������������
mmml-���
mmmmmml-�������������5���������kkkkkkkkkkaa���������[���Xkkkkkka�+!Oi4��pүJ�k��k���AWu]��E�0cd  ��r,a�\4A �e�
�7�a�����~�x`����s��j;�v0�,��D%A7��� -���5����\���2@��k��s�P�O�5��_�5���s'���85�������0�������5����(�f�����p���������@6��p{������7����w#`��3/���M?����
�����õ����_���������X~���
��������}���8���>��|>���|?ᇲ�#������?�����{����������������������뿿����������������������������}���������������u����������������������������������An������������������]_�����������������������_���/�����u��_��]k���u�k��u��?岲���������������������������=����5�R@�3@<3����;�TE��\��j��H?���I������[
��ڿ۽^���_��m_�����l+���W������������j�����{j�{IZ�����ZV������6���5�WW��������֯��5�յ�~����¿�U���M������j�ﶯ��Z��kk�����6������Z������ڿ�Uj��V��^�_�����a���j�����k�W�ߵ��������w�����'~O��Y��.����;��{����[�ֻ��;������[���������<%���������G��� ��R�;���������[��������~�������ֿ��׾��I������I��������}���/�����?��o]����������Y�������������W������+�﷥|?�����[~���~��k߷��������������������]m���W���_�������߶��O���W�����Ӯ������z����ޭRo������������]*������[��[���־�b�������������J�����������k~��[��������B���}}�����w�����_���u����i?k�����_���������������������������������_w������}?������_����?������_�����������������<�?��@��� ������߿�W�����/��W�������U������~����U_����_��o�����M�����K��k�U���~��_��m���_�O��5�M=8|DDDG������������Y�dYR�Ws� ��f)�R@C%�|���s,� R!�L:i�����BX�&v�̃�#1��������T-4����  5�A��0��^�L*i��k�z��YN%/���W��i}W��]Uk�A������T�Zߧ�|z�k��V���������izIW�*�T}����T�T��n5������u�޾�w_�� ��Y9��A����r�Φj2V�1��@OR��$5D� �D�22Tԗ2D|�f�*�xM4�L&0��AH(M0���I�
5L=��0�*a0��A��V�0P�   �a0��� ��e#
    I���56����f ��A�4A�`��P�A�C�b ���}�'��B
b�T�
b[NJ���+mT-�i�
U
��節R��<H'KI���J���m���:�iz�꒭6�    T:h'Y   ]�ݭ5�X{�&�i�oUF�T��u
�-#�ч�ui-'�$N�(Kݦ�FxK
�u�%`�}G�0��ʊ�k8�IV��zMW����^:�ʎ��.����_���P�B���Ru�K~�^�%��?�k'N��N�8�/�U�I�:_��t�~�����b�U�_㊤�����Z����5U�����B���㥯Z�?�U�/�Ʃ�֖�uH�Y���f��~�~���޾�����u�y}�
�$�
���%~�/��_�ҪZ�5���W���*�/����j����_��V���~�C�W�   z��T�������������_���I�j��]W�����������K�J��ׯK��z]~�aK������U�Ҡ���-t�������U�_���%�O�U�^�?�I&�_��V���뤒_Z����+�?�~������������_��NH������ZT��-��Ʃ^��t�"�?���Fӥ����Oץ ��^����)�(5�  ~�*�K�_z��i:�׽H ����k���Z�A�����U�S����^�_����]kկ��j����_Z����7���Q�K¥���]UV�/I�U���M�Լ'I%�z�}zZ��k�_�_��Wk�K��P ��륤��3U�}-V����KI����T�UZ֪9���T5�A���v���Z�����]~�K����GU꿯�{�zU���Y��K�_���=���o�c_�֟�ݸ������R�/��z��_�K���uU�Z�k���*���mjy.���8u�q-��Ν����_�UY���mY__Z��li�V5��Ջ��z��S�w����|}�%�z�J�
`��X8|P��;֗T��1�x�Ԇ*� ��j�_�p��a�нҾ��ot�j�U�    &�R�6�\*���*j�Z�nUB����Z��������ϫK���M=+JH����%��`�W�:�&�W�����A���OUUkծ�g�M0����څ  �¶�¦�0�P������a4���a�bHP��!����(I���,!AR&`���
�,&P�I�4�aBŦ�T$AB��i�Dj��""T�{b""4*"""""9ia��¿��t� ��zu_Pz�����޿{uK��_ۥ��_n�-p�(zi�հ�a<77�AA'S�A�m^""#�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������_� 9PdG����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������e��`�    c����� @ �             �          �                                                 �      �      �      �         (       )           ,     ,
```

Comment: I'd use itextsharp but there are a couple of options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699407/how-to-convert-from-string-into-pdf

Comment: I am looking into iText7, but how do you use it

Answer (score 0):

Re: The PDF.  The PDF is an 7 Bit ASCII file I believe, and WriteAllText will create and write the file in UTF-8 format.  The characters inserted by UTF-8 at the lead of the file can break things when you are viewing the file.

Use the version of WriteAllText that allows you to encode this properly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_

The Tiff is a binary file.  You can't just dump it into a UTF8 text file and expect that to go well.  It won't.

Comment: This is not working 
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\testUTF7.pdf", fileData, Encoding.UTF7);

Comment: Also how do I save the tiff file